# Zoom in and zoom out in Bluestack without keyboard

Tags: bluestacks

The way to zoom in and zoom out in bluestack is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse wheel</kbd>.

Without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, mouse wheel will only scroll up and down, something that can already be done in Clash of Clan by click-and-drag.

I want to change the way Bluestack behaves so that scroll up and down means zoom in and out, no need to use the keyboard at all.

Is it possible to do that?